# Acquiring laptop drivers

Tags: drivers

I recently got hold of a Packard Bell Easynote G45. It has a fresh install of XP on, but it has no drivers, and I cannot find a source for them.

Generally most manufacturers have a page, but Packard Bell don't list the G45 anyway, and googling results in a lot of iffy websites asking me to download a .exe file.

Where is the best resource for drivers, if the manufacturer does not supply them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked, too, and I couldn't find your exact model but I found two that might be very close when looking under "legacy products":

- [EasyNote BG45](ftp://ftp.download.packardbell.com/NOTEBOOK/EasyNote%20BG45%20series/)
- [EasyNote GN45](ftp://ftp.download.packardbell.com/NOTEBOOK/EasyNote%20GN45%20series/)

You could try those and see if they work.

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds! This was the closest thing I could find as well.

Comment: Hmm those links don't seem to work, sound like my best bet too!

The web page at ftp://ftp.download.packardbell.com/NOTEBOOK/EasyNote%20GN45%20series/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Comment: Any idea why the links don't work @Joel Coehoorn ?

Comment: @dan hey, I missed your comments from before and just saw this today because you marked it accepted.  The links work for me from at least two different computers, so I think their site might have had a problem.  I want to confirm that the links do work for you now, and also that one of them was able to resolve the problem for you or if you're just accepting this to keep your percentage from dropping. If one of the drivers worked, which one was it?

Comment: hey dude, sorry I tried again today and they worked, so I accepted the answer. I really appreciate the help, thanks! (It was the GN45)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried calling Packard Bell and requesting the correct link to the drivers?

Otherwise, I would probably start by trying to identify the hardware using the HardwareID property from the device in Device Manager and look up the item on http://www.pcidatabase.com - then look over Packard Bell's site for other models that use the same drivers/hardware and download them.

(But the phone call is likely the simplist, quickest method).